# regexp Matching capture and exp_send

Tags: regex, expect

Currently I have a script which is extracting the line #  number from the below menu response which has the SNMP user I’m interested in “SalVhugoV3”.

Here is the menu response in blue

Select an SNMP user:
  1) cmssnmp
  2) atlas
  3) SalVhugoV3
Enter choice (1-3):

This working section of the script looks for the string containing “SalVhugoV3”  and takes away the option #3 as that’s the option of the user it’s looking for. Then sends “3” as the snmpuserChoice for the “Enter choice”  prompt.

## Choose V3 User From the List/Menu, grep for $V3USER and send it's number

```
    expect -re ".*\\(.*\\):" {
    append rawOut $expect_out(buffer)
    regexp { .*(([0-9])\) [puts $V3USER].*) } $expect_out(buffer) cmdOut snmpUser snmpUserChoice
    exp_send -- "$snmpUserChoice\r"
}
```

I’m trying to do the same thing but with this extended  response , as you can see the option for the user I’m looking for in this case  is  option “5” as it contains “SalVhugoV3” at the end of the string.  I believe this is what needs to change “ regexp { .*(([0-9])) [puts $V3USER].*) } “  but  I don’t exactly how to modify in order for it to grab the option “5” number so it can be sent via the “exp_send”.

Select an SNMP Connection to delete: 
  1) Connection to NMS: Host 135.9.60.143, Port 162, User cmssnmp
  2) Connection to SAL: Host 135.9.158.252, Port 162, User cmssnmp
  3) Connection to SAL: Host 135.9.158.236, Port 162, User cmssnmp
  4) Connection to NMS: Host 135.105.6.67, Port 162, User atlas
  5) Connection to SAL: Host 135.60.25.147, Port 162, User SalVhugoV3
Enter choice (1-5):

## Choose V3 User From the List/Menu, grep for $V3USER and send it's number

```
    expect -re ".*\\(.*\\):" {
    append rawOut $expect_out(buffer)
    regexp { .*(([0-9])\) [puts $V3USER].*) } $expect_out(buffer) cmdOut snmpUser snmpUserChoice
    exp_send -- "$snmpUserChoice\r"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regexp "((\[0-9\])\\)\[^\\)\]*$V3USER)" $expect_out(buffer) cmdOut snmpUser snmpUserChoice
```

For V3USER=atlas it would give:

> snmpUser='4) Connection to NMS: Host 135.105.6.67, Port 162, User atlas'
>
> snmpUserChoice='4'

For better readability and to avoid escaping:

```
set gen_expr {([0-9])\)[^\)]*}
set spec_expr "($choice_expr$V3USER)"
regexp $spec_expr $expect_out(buffer) cmdOut snmpUser snmpUserChoice
```

BTW: term `{ ... [puts $V3USER] }` puzzles me. There is no escaping in braces so this is just interpreted as piece of regexp thus expects one of the characters 'p', 'u', 't', 's', ' ', $', etc ...